# Javascript - Simulate click on div element

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to simulate a click on any of these div elements. When they are clicked in the browser, the color around the button changes.

Before being clicked:

```
<div class="MatchModeQuestionGridBoard">
<div class="MatchModeQuestionGridBoard-tiles">
<div class="MatchModeQuestionGridBoard-tile">
<div class="MatchModeQuestionGridTile" touch-action="auto">
<div class="MatchModeQuestionGridTile-content">
<div class="FormattedText notranslate MatchModeQuestionGridTile-text lang-es" style="font-size: 12px;">
<div style="display: block;">ocho</div></div></div></div></div>
```

After being clicked:

```
<div class="MatchModeQuestionGridBoard">
<div class="MatchModeQuestionGridBoard-tiles">
<div class="MatchModeQuestionGridBoard-tile">
<div class="MatchModeQuestionGridTile is-selected" touch-action="auto">
<div class="MatchModeQuestionGridTile-content">
<div class="FormattedText notranslate MatchModeQuestionGridTile-text lang-es" style="font-size: 12px;">
<div style="display: block;">ocho</div></div></div></div></div>
```

Something else I tried:

```
var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent("click", true, true);
document.getElementsByClassName("MatchModeQuestionGridTile-content")[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

I've tried to make a chrome extension with javascript to do this with a simulated click. I have tried `document.getElementsByClassName("MatchModeQuestionGridTile-content")[0].click()`,
and

In the full html, there are more class members of `MatchModeQuestionGridTile-content`, which is why I have the `[0]`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please include all information on this question, rather than linking to it on pastebin.

Comment: I tried to do that, but it was saying my code wasn't formatted correctly or something and wouldn't allow me to post the question.